# Как программно создать пункты в PopupMenu?

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

Делаю так:

```
     private void showMenu1(View v) {
    PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    menu1.inflate(R.menu.popupmenu); 
    menu1.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.subChSetOrb: onClSetOrb(); 
                    return true;
                default: return false;
            }
        }
    });
    menu1.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu) {  } // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDismiss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
    menu1.show();
}
```

Разметка меню хранится в

```
R.menu.popupmenu
```

а я хочу создавать и удалять пункты программно. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто - получите ссылку на меню и добавляйте:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
popup.getMenu().add(0, 0, 0, "title");
```

Comment: А как понять что выбрано? Т.е.здесь switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.subChSetOrb: на что поменять?

Comment: @kaaa, просто наведите мышь на метод и увидите к нему java-doc. А там ответ на ваш вопрос: `MenuItem add (int groupId, 
                int itemId, 
                int order, 
                int titleRes)` Вам нужен `itemId`

Comment: Все заработало! Благодарю!